# Set default user in terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, user-account

I just formatted my Mac and upgrade it to El Capitan, 
When I open Terminal I see that I am always logged in as root:

[image]

How can I get my usual user name every time I open a new Terminal window,

I have tried `su -l username` and it worked, however when I close the window and open another the root user comes back.

Comment: Did you enable the root user, yourself?

Comment: No, the issue appears immediately just after installing

Comment: Is just the prompt wrong or are you really logged in as root? What does `id -a` return?

Comment: @patrix I am really logged in as a root

Comment: Can you move all your .bashrc, .profile etc. files away and open a new tab in Terminal? Still root?

Comment: Also, enable ssh and log in as username@localhost. Do you get logged in correctly or as root?

Comment: That does seem very strange; to be the root user, by default, on a fresh install.